# Nice admin interface for Spring applications similar to Django Admin

Tags: java, django, kotlin

I am a big fan of building Spring based Java applications. Recently I worked a little in  Django and saw the Django Admin that is automatically generated for the app - and  it blew my mind. Since then I am looking for something similar for the Java/Kotlin world - Spring preferably, but any Java/Kotlin framework is acceptable.

I know about https://www.jhipster.tech/ and https://github.com/api-platform/admin but they are all a little bit different.

To summarize - what is the nearest Django Admin equivalent in Java world?

Comment: oh man, I searched in hope of  finding an answer to the same question ) but for now I see it remains unanswered. Django Admin indeed is awesome...